# How to rewrite images imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm using imagemagick functions for compess. I need help with replacing an image in function optimizeimage();

```
$path = '/home/bitrix/ext_www/host.svarbi.ru/';
$input = __DIR__."ttt/image/tmp/images.jpg";
$output = __DIR__."ttt/image/tmp/images1.jpg";


function optimizeimage($input,$output) 
{
    $image = new Imagick($input);
    $image->stripimage();
    $image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $image->setImageCompressionQuality(30);
    $image->writeImageFile($output);
}
optimizeimage($input,$output);
```

But I need to rewrite image by imagemagick - how can I do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Why are you globbing inside `optimizeimage()` when it is already called from inside a loop? http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (example from http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php)

```
<?php
$image = 'image.jpg';
$imagick = new Imagick($image);
clearstatcache(dirname($image));
$imagick->writeImage($image);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for help!